# Do GitHub repos show the current repo tag somewhere?

Tags: github

Right now to find out the current tag of a repo I have to clone the repo and run `git tag`.

Is the tag published somewhere on github?

Just want to make sure I'm not overlooking it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formatted url will display the list of tags of the repository, with the most recent at the top

```
 https://github.com/{:owner}/{:repository}/tags
```

You also can access this list by clicking on the `Releases` link on the main page of the repository, then on the `Tags` link.

**Note:** FWIW, in git parlance, there's no such thing as a *current* tag.

Tags are basically labels, names. They can exist in two flavors:

- lightweight pointers to some commits (or trees (think directories) or even blobs (think files))
- annotated pointers to the same kind of git objects as above. The *annotation* adds some additional information as the identity of the person who created the tag, the date of the tagging and optionally a cryptographic signature.

Tags are most of the time used to stamp a version. They can also be used to "bookmark" a specific object (while doing a code review, for instance).

So depending of what one use tags for, the *current* tags may be:

- The tag pointing to the most recent commit
- The latest created tag (if annotated)
- The last one when their names are alpha sorted (or whatever sort mechanism matching the tag naming convention for this specific repository)